# How is this HTML5 brick falling down?

Tags: css, html, layout

I've prepared a sample jsfiddle to show the problem I'm currently facing with my layout: when I insert a content dynamically into a particular element (the brick), the element sinks down together with its parent in a way that's beyond my understanding of HTML/CSS. When I remove the content, the original layout is restored, unless I'm using Chrome... then it would retain its position and fall down again when a new content is inserted.

Proof of concept: http://jsfiddle.net/GADk9/

The checkbox in the example simply toggles a text inside the brick, nothing more. I wonder where the above margin (is it?) comes from.

Here is a complete HTML5 document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
<title>HTML5 Falling Brick - What is this?</title>
<style>
#brick {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: solid black medium;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#contrail { background-color: lightblue; width: 20em; }
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Click me twice
            <input onchange="document.getElementById('brick').innerHTML = this.checked ? 'FALL!!!' : ''" type='checkbox'></input>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div id='pit'>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id='contrail'>
            <div>
                <div id='brick'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## Update

After reading again my question I realize it may suggest the incorrect impression that what I'm actually trying to accomplish is fixing some HTML.
To emphasize the point explicitly, I don't need to change anything here. The example with the brick is just a funny demo of the issue I'm observing.
I'm really interested in understanding **what is causing the elements to change their position when a content is inserted** in an arrangement like this.

Comment: How is this HTML5? o_o

Comment: I don't get it. The fiddle, Firefox and Chrome all work the same to me. The rule #pit>*>* doesn't make any sense either since you're saying everything under everything under #pit.

Comment: @Rob I think the selector >* is not recursive, so `#pit>*` would only look to its direct children, not its grand children.

Comment: The * selector is recursive. It will select every element under #pit.

Comment: @Goodwine my sample code is HTML5, but in fact I don't mind believing the same effect could be reproduced with a previous HTML version as well. ^__^

Comment: @Rob I think `#pit *` will select every descendant of `#pit` whereas `#pit>*` will select only its children

Comment: @Ejay - I got disconnected between not understanding the sense of the overall rule and what could actually happen and I think you are right.

Comment: It's obvious... you're using a table. And tables cannot escape the laws of gravity :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier to understand if you simplify the markup to just a couple of cells each containing a div.

```
<div class="cell left">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell middle">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell right">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Then assign each div a different height with some CSS like this.

```
.cell {
  display:table-cell;
  background-color:black;
  width:200px;
}

.inner {
  background-color:silver;
}

.left .inner {
  height:80px;
}
.middle .inner {
  height:140px;
}
.right .inner {
  height:100px;
}
```

By default these inner divs are vertically aligned to their baseline. So, without any text, all the divs align along the bottom of the cells:

```
       +------+
       |      |
       |      +------+
+------+      |      |
|      |      |      |
|      |      |      |
+------+------+------+
```

However, if you add text to any one of them, that div will be pushed down so that the baseline of the first line of text lines up with the bottom edges of the other divs.

```
       +------+
       |      |
       |      |
+------+      |      
|      |      +------+
|      |      |Text  |
+------+------+      |
              |      |
              +------+
```

As has been pointed out by others, you can change what happens by setting a different `vertical-align` property. For example, adding `vertical-align:top` to the *.cell* selector would give you something like this:

```
+------+------+------+
|      |      |Text  |
|      |      |      |
+------+      |      |
       |      +------+
       |      |
       +------+
```

I find it easiest to play around with this sort of thing in codepen, where you can see the changes as you make them. [Here's an example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzHqr) to experiment with.

Comment: Good analysis. Sheds light on the problem well.

Comment: Thanks James, I appreciate your clear explanation. The bounty goes to the answer that pointed out the vertical-align issue first.

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
<div id='pit'>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='contrail'>
        <div>
            <div id='brick'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you are using

```
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }
```

Now here is our problem as it says `#pit` is table and `#pit>*` is a table-cell it is adding up `height: 4em;` every time.

Now here is my solution.

```
#pit { display: block; }
#pit>* { display: table; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; display: table-cell;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAbhishekk/GADk9/28/

Comment: The extra space above the brick is there due to those blank div's above contrail as it is acting like a table.

Comment: The extra space is there due to the vertical alignment of the block.  Not because of those empty divs.  An empty div wouldn't show in a table based display.  It should have some content in order to do so.

Comment: Moving the table down to the child level, and table-cell down to the grandchild eliminates the table -> single-row -> cells thing that the op had going on. This effectively makes each child a table with a single row and cell, resulting in two tables instead of one.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen behavioral differences between browsers when using table, table-row and table-cell display many times. To begin with, I never use them as there is always a better solution. However, to your question:

When dealing with CSS that is intended to behave like tables, it helps to think a little old school.

It turns out the magic CSS property to make your POC in the Fiddle behave properly is vertical-align. In fact, this fixes the odd insertion of additional vertical space in all the browsers, not just Chrome, while also fixing the problem of Chrome retaining the additional space.

Check out this tiny revision to the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rtzeK/

```
#brick {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: solid black medium;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#contrail { background-color: lightblue; width: 20em; }
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; vertical-align: top; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }
```

In the fiddle I linked, I simply set the children that are display: table-cell to have the additional property, vertical-align: top. As it turns out, you can set it to middle or bottom, all with the same effect.  It stops the misbehavior - apparently Chrome needs to be told *how to behave* in this scenario.

I do find it a little odd how Chrome is misbehaving, and it appears to be a bug. That said, I go back to my previous statement about avoiding these display property values like the plague. Combinations of display: inline, inline-block, block, combined with relative and absolute positioning used appropriately across parents and children renders other troublesome css properties, e.g. float, unnecessary.

Cheers

Comment: There is not always a better solution.  Tell me how you'd get an unordered list to expand horizontally across an allocated space with equal undefined widths without breaking?  Table-cell and table displays definitely have their place, and I feel it's unproductive to suggest otherwise.

Comment: Ooh! A challenge. Love it. I'll fiddle it up tonight when I have a little free time :)  Cheers.

Comment: I'm interested to see the solution.  Display: inline; White-space: nowrap; and Width: <<Total Elements / 100>>% will get you 95% of the way there, but it doesn't account for an unspecified amount added to the list without delving into javascript.  Realized I came off as a bit churlish with that last comment.  My apologies.

Comment: Oops posted the answer to this in your answer instead of mine...

http://jsfiddle.net/gFFYj 

The extra space between li elements is due to whitespace, e.g. line breaks. The above fiddle presents two ways to achieve what you've asked for without break and ensuring the container width is not exceeded, while each of the li elements is the same width. The first way is with float: left (ugh) the second way is with the li elements minified to the same line. Cheers

Comment: By the way, to my point re using inline, block and inline-block exclusively (which I realize is just my preference based on my css experience dating back to the dark ages of netscape 4...) -- here is another fiddle of the original posted question that eliminates the table and table-cell in lieu of block and inline-block. Look at this one, it's interesting. When not using vertical-align the behavior is grow/shrink and with vertical-align it stays a constant size. Better, no?

http://jsfiddle.net/wTtfE/

Comment: Sorry, one more thing, so many thoughts on this topic:
I'm sure we all agree that the days of using TABLE for layout purposes are well in the past. It is semantically incorrect to do so. If it is data that should be displayed as a table great, otherwise BAD juju.
So, isn't it likewise just as semantically incorrect to use CSS table, table-row and table-cell to make a browser display divs or other elements like a table? Isn't this just a fancy way of doing what we used to do in the mid to late 90s because CSS hadn't evolved?

Comment: @JimSpeaker With the exception of Chrome, I don't see any differences between browsers here. Given that the default `vertical-alignment` is `baseline`, it's possible that an empty block has a different baseline than a block with content inside, and that would require the user agent to reposition the block when a content is inserted or removed. This looks like a plausible theory to me, although I'd like to verify it and nobody can explain the details.

Comment: @ft1 - I agree, with the problem posted the sole browser that is behaving strangely is Chrome. My mention of problems with various browsers and the table, table-cell display settings referred simply to past experience including many older versions of the browsers. Your point re baseline default is an interesting one, and I agree that sounds plausible. With no content, what baseline? Exactly. Hm.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best idea I can come up with, I hope I nail it or that it's as least close to it.
In your CSS rules you have:

```css
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }
```

which tells the browser that `#pit` is a table, and that all its children are cells (while the grandchildren are what they are since display is not being enforced by CSS)

## Here I see 2 problems :

### Problem 1

Inside `#pit` you have:

```
<div>
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id='contrail'>
    <div>
        <div id='brick'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Pay attention to the children because you have 2, and the selector `#pit>*` says **EVERY `#pit` CHILD**
I would change that CSS rules for this:

```css
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>#contrail { display: table-cell; }
#pit>#contrail>* { height: 4em; }
```

But be careful on what you want because this makes the children from `#pit>#contrail` 4em high, not the inner child `#brick`, maybe this is what you want, but pay attention to it.

### Problem 2 @ Chrome (not present if you "solve" the first problem)

I'm not sure what I'm saying here, but... could this be a webkit bug? does this happen with Opera as well?
EDIT: Opera does not behave like Chrome, it returns to the normal layout, so maybe it is not a webkit bug after all :/

So you have a table, and table cells, but the browser then thinks *"Wait... if this is a table, and this is a cell... Where is the row!?"*, so it creates a "ghost row" so it can be happy. However I'm not sure what does 'it' think when you remove the text because it "works" normally. If you look at the developer tools, you will see that there is no actual row element or anything similar.
When you "re-add" the text, the browser is mind=blow because table layouts. So it re-creates the row again (stretching `#pit`), probably because the "ghost rows" are not cleared, or because `#pit`'s height is never recalculated again and it only increments when the ghost row spawns.

If you want to leave the same CSS rules, you would have to do something like:

```css
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-row; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: You need not include table rows with display:table. Using this property does not make an element a table but only displays it as such. For example: http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table

Comment: @Rob You are right there, however the browser will "create" a row (and table if necessary) to display something table-cell ish when the appropriate elements are missing, therefore causing this (I think)

Comment: It will not. At least not in the HTML if that's what you are saying.

Comment: @Rob No, I don't mean in the HTML, I mean in the guts of the browser, but as I said before, this is just my imagination going rampant :P

Comment: @Goodwine Table-row isn't used like that in display:table.  The row is implied if none is specified, and only used to designate breaks in inline content when necessary.  A table row is an organizing element, not a layout element, and thus has very little style actually applied to it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, the easiest answers are overlooked.  Instead of resetting the content to nothing (e.g. ""), simply start the empty content as a non-breaking space, and reset it back to a non-breaking space.  Table cells don't render when they don't have content.  A non-breaking space is considered content by the cell, and thus it renders correctly.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GADk9/73/)

**Here's the rub:**

You need to add this rule to your #brick block:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

and you need to give some content to your empty table cell that's supposed to render content, accomplished this way:

```
<div id='contrail'>
    <div>
        <div id='brick'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Voila, it's fixed in Chrome and displays the same way everywhere else.  This is an old-school problem with tables.  It appears Chrome decided to be faithful to how they originally behaved back in the bad-old-days.

Alternatively, for a purely CSS solution, you can add the content rule to the #brick block as well:

```
vertical-align: top;
content: '&nbsp;';
```

This works the exact same way.  Enjoy!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GADk9/76/

Removing the &nbsp; it still works just fine. The vertical-align: top css is the key, as I posted yesterday.

Comment: @JimSpeaker You're correct.  I agree that thinking old-school was the solution here, and I admit I didn't give your comment a full look prior to posting my own.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like chrome is not happy about having display:table-cell inside display:table without display:table-row somewhere in between.

If you add it (and give brick some width), it will stop falling:

```
#brick {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: solid black medium;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
#contrail { background-color: lightblue; width: 20em; }
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-row; }
#pit>*>* { display: table-cell; }
#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }
```

Comment: display:table does not require a table-row.

Comment: @artem when inserting an element with `{ display: table-row; }`, the document tree changes, and so `#pit>*>* { height: 4em; }` would have to be rewritten as `#pit>*>*>* { height: 4em; }`.

Comment: @ft1 I did not propose inserting anything in the DOM - your HTML has  enough divs already. I just checked with jsfiddle what happens if the ones immediately below `#pit` were styled with `display: table-row`

Comment: @artem: ok, but then you're not just restyling the divs immediately under `#pit`, you're also changing the layout structure from two cells in the same (implicit) row into two rows with one cell each.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; }
```

The above causes it to expand (& not contract). Is this expected behaviour? No since it does not happen on IE or Firefox, I believe it is a Chrome bug that misinterprets `display: table` & `display: table-cell` behaviours. It does not seem to recalculate the height of the table-cell, in your case `<div id="contrail">` when the text is removed.

[Have a look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PU57W/1/) - I've replaced the divs with actual tables. Each time the text is populated, the table-cell's height expands but it contracts back to the original size when the text is cleared. I would conclude that it is a Chrome bug since the purpose of this CSS display mode is to mimick the use of `<table><td>`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there was a weird rule:

```
#brick {
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: solid black medium;
    border-radius: 1em;
    color: red;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height:2em;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:2em;
}
#contrail { background-color: lightblue; width: 20em; }
#pit { display: table; }
#pit>* { display: table-cell; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GADk9/77/

Answer (score 0):

I noticed just adding a

```
   <p> around your text </p>
```

solved the problem

here's a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TDsouza/aan2D/)

Comment: Well, this reduces the shift to 1 pixel (!)

Answer (score 0):

Answer: The browser does not understand your html/css layout combination, because it is not formatted to official specifications. Improperly formatted HTML will make the browser display elements improperly.

A table cell MUST have a parent table row:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-td-element

A table cell is NOT allowed as a direct child element of the table element:

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/tabular-data.html#the-table-element